# iPod Touch 3rd gen

Tags: ipod, ios, touch

I'm looking to buy a 3rd gen iPod Touch, largely for the portable music aspect. However, playing games is fun, so I wanted to check how out of date the iOS on the 3rd gen version will be. How far can the iOS be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5.1.1

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4393895?start=0&tstart=0

Hardware limitation.